# Login through one additional column in Devise - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have one column in `db` , which contains either `'c' or 't'` and on my login page , I contain these values in `select box` within form along with `username and password` .Login scenario is that an `email` e.g `xyz@example.com` can register two times , one time with `'c'` and one time with `'t'` but not twice for any flag . means i've this validation in model

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :account
```

how can i customize `devise` so that i could login using select box .

**Important point** is that `'c' and 't'` are very different from each other that's why when we select either of these we need to redirect according to that . options can't mix . Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: What are `c` and `t` exactly? `roles`?

Comment: @Pavan yes you can say